# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting while executing a raw query on the database with flask

Tags: python, sql, flask, formatting

I am trying to search my database with a key word(s) using raw sql in flask, and I am getting the following error TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting.

Here is the code that I am executing

```
@app.route("/submit_search")
def submit_search():

    search_words = request.args['search_words']  

    db_search= db.execute("SELECT title FROM books WHERE  title  LIKE "%search_words%"").fetchall()

    print(db_search)
```

Comment: `. . . "%search_words%""` is attempting to do string formatting using the `%` operator. What are you trying to do there? If you want quotes in the string itself, you'll need to escape them with backslashes: `"\%search_words\%"`.

Answer (score 1):

Keyword 'Like' doesn't take multiple values. So if you are getting a list of words try to break it up.

And you can try string formatting like

```py
sql =  """SELECT title FROM books WHERE  title  LIKE "%{}%""""".format(search_word)

db_search = db.execute(sql).fetchall()
```